# Average question, missing a step somewhere.

Tags: arithmetic, average

A store sells a microwave for 24.99 and a toaster for 17.99, last week they sold 12 toasters and 7 microwaves, what was the average sell price for all items sold?

Comment: The dollar signs are messing up the formatting because we use them to set off MathJax.  It is probably easiest to remove them, as the question does not depend on the currency used.  Where are you stuck?  What was the total revenue?  How many items did you sell?

Comment: I changed it. I think I'm missing a step, I simply determined the avenge of 17.99 and 24.99; 21.49.  I'm being told that's wrong and and I need to do each one separately, which I don't get.

Comment: @JasonWolf The "*average sell price for all items sold*" is the total cost divided by the total number of items.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem of weighted avereages. So the answer should be $$\frac {24.99 \times 7 + 17.99 \times 12}{7 + 12} $$ so the answer comes out to be $20.5689$